# Modern Type Theory vs. Martin Löf Type Theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, type-theory

I have been reading Martin Löf notes on type theory to get a historical feel for the subject and I find some of the terminology confusing (e.g. distinction judgements and propositions, between proofs and derivations in a formal system, and between sets/types and categories, etc.) It seems modern treatments of type theory (HoTT, etc.) do not require these discussions and such fine distinctions and opt to jump right into the rules of type theory. Is there a reason for this, beyond pedagogy?

My ultimate goal is to get up to speed with HoTT, but many experts mention that reading the HoTT book with out a strong background is not helpful. What supplementary sources would you suggest?

Martin Löf notes:
https://archive-pml.github.io/martin-lof/pdfs/Bibliopolis-Book-retypeset-1984.pdf

Comment: I've read the whole book with zero prior knowledge of type theory. It's only hard at first.

Comment: Except there was this lecture that helped me at some point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6hXn6QCu0k

Comment: Thompson's notes on type theory are a great introduction.  Even that should be supplemented with a bit of basic category theory, which you can get from many resources. https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/ttfp.pdf